# Undefined `self` within recursive function body not report NameError

Tags: python

I happened run such a snippet which I pick from within a Class method and remove the `self` in arguments, but retain it within body.

```
def bi_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None) -> int:
    if hi == None:
        hi = len(a)

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')

    if lo == hi:
        return None

    mid = (lo + hi) // 2

    if x == a[mid]:
        return x
    if x > a[mid]:
        lo = mid + 1
        return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
    if x < a[mid]:
        hi = mid
        return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)

print(bi_search([1, 2, 3, 4], 3))
```

It works perfectly and report no errors, 
Why it does not report NameError.

[image]

If tried self.bi_search it report NameError

```
In [2]: self.bi_search                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f458d3bc4fee> in <module>
----> 1 self.bi_search

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: That sounds like you defined a global variable named `self` and didn't realize, or forgot about it.

Comment: No, see my update screeshot @user2357112

Comment: @Jonas Yeah, that's the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work. Your code just never happens to hit those conditional statements involving `self`. If it did, it would produce a `NameError`.

Comment: Specifically: for this input, the initial value of `mid` is `2`, and `[1, 2, 3, 4][2]` is `3`, which matches the searched-for value immediately. `return x` happens and the rest of the function is not considered. Python does not consider whether `self` has a value in scope until the moment it is actually used.